# How to make Intellij IDEA show Java type hints for inferred local variables only on hover?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, type-inference, type-hinting, java-10

Intellij IDEA shows type hints for variables created with the new 'var' feature from Java 10.

However, inferred types are so long sometimes that the line length ends up exceeding the width guide as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image]

Is it possible to make Intellij IDEA only show type hints on hover?

Answer (score 3):

It's [not possible at the moment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165655), you can vote for the linked feature request.

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround**

Disable type hints for implicit types:
[image]

Use `show type info` on expression you want to see the type for.

Shortcut on windows `Ctrl+Shift+P`
[image]